# Is the function thread-safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, thread-safety

I want to avoid calling RegisterClassEx() multiple times from threads within a process. For this I have modified existing function as below.

There are constraints imposed by current code structure on using alternative ways to achieve thread-safety, hence for now I am trying to stick to minimal amount of changes.

Please let me know your thoughts on code below.

```
foo()
{   
    static ATOM atom = 0;
    if( atom == 0 )
    {
        {
            EnterCriticalSection(&m_CSRegisterClassEx);
            if( atom == 0 )
            {
                atom = RegisterClassEx(&tCls);      

                if( atom == 0)
                {
                    ERROR(L"RegisterClassEx failed! );
                    LeaveCriticalSection(&m_CSRegisterClassEx); 
                    return 0; 
                }
                else
                {
                    ERROR(L"RegisterClassEx good!");
                    LeaveCriticalSection(&m_CSRegisterClassEx);
                    return atom;
                }
            }

        }
    }
    else
    {
        ERROR(L"using atom[%ld] from last call!", atom);
        return atom; 
    }
}
```

enter code here

Comment: You have an obvious data race on `atom`, making your code ill-formed.

Comment: Whenever you are accessing a value from multiple threads, it needs to be guarded either inside an explicit mutex to ensure mutual exclusion, or wrapped in a std::atomic<>.

Comment: If that was my code I would write a function `ATOM get_atom()` that does all the `RegisterClassEx` stuff minus the critical section stuff and just write `ATOM foo(){ static ATOM atom = get_atom(); return atom;}` and rely on [magic statics (requires VS 2015)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx).

Comment: I believe multiple threads can find the 1st if statement true, out of them only one will pass the EnterCriticalSection() and then register the class  while others are on the sleep queue. When they awake up and go inside critical section, the first thing I do is check for value of atom again and this will be by now updated. Does this suffice? Which code path I am missing?

Comment: You are missing the code path where 1 thread changes `atom` inside the critical section and another thread reads `atom` outside the critical section, making this a classic data race.

Comment: The code is unsafe. This is an implementation of the double-checked locking pattern, and to make it safe you will need to use memory barriers (consider using `std::atomic<int> ATOM` instead of `int ATOM`).

Comment: @utnapistim `ATOM` is the type name in this case (it is a typedef provided by Windows)

Comment: [Here is more information on why your code is not thread safe.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040308-00/?p=40363/)

Comment: Apparently [`ATOM` is a 16 bit integer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa921831.aspx), so `std::atomic<ATOM> atom` should work.

Comment: @andlabs, in that case, it should probably be `std::atomic<ATOM> atom{ 0 }` instead of `ATOM atom = 0;`.

Comment: @andlabs The post is no longer correct for C++11 and VS2015.

Comment: Yes, the post predates C++11, but I highly doubt the semantics of the language have changed (that is, `std::atomic` doesn't invalidate the error, it just provides an alternative solution - if it is even a valid solution; I don't know enough about the C++11 threading model to know). VS2015 is still really new; not everyone is going to be using it by now just yet. In fact, we don't know what compiler the OP is using.

Comment: @andlabs Iirc the c++11 guarantees that a static variable inside a method is only assigned one without having to worry about race conditions. Hence the code shown here is still invalid, but Raymond's sample is now well defined (and the preferred way to since the issue at hand)

Comment: @Voo Good to know; thanks

Comment: @dpb actually, why are you trying to register the same class from any of multiple threads in the first place? It's clear that you know that a registered class is available process-wide; why not register the class before spawning any threads? That way, you avoid having to make things harder for yourself! Is there some preexisting architectural design that prevents this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double check pattern is not thread safe, check this article http://www.aristeia.com/Papers/DDJ_Jul_Aug_2004_revised.pdf

Here is a solution, similar to Qt's Q_GLOBAL_STATIC implementationand chrome's signleton implementation.

```
template<class T>
class  TwStaticObject
{
public:
TwStaticObject(void)
    : p(nullptr)
    , x(0)
{

}
~TwStaticObject(void)
{

}

struct Deleter
{
    Deleter(TwStaticObject& This)
    : __this(This)
    {
        ;
    }
    ~Deleter()
    {
        if (__this.p)
        {
            delete __this.p;
            __this.p = 0;
            __this.x = 0;

        }
    }
    TwStaticObject& __this;
};

static T* singletonInstance(TwStaticObject& thisobj)
{ 
    if (InterlockedCompareExchange(&thisobj.x, 1, 0) == 0)
    {
        static T* obj = new T;
        InterlockedExchangePointer((volatile PVOID *)&thisobj.p, (PVOID)obj);
        static Deleter ThisDelter(thisobj);
    }
    else
    {
        while (thisobj.p == nullptr)
        {
            Sleep(0);
        }
    }
    return thisobj.p;
}

T* volatile p ;
volatile long x ;
};


#define  TwDefine_SingleTon(Type, FUN)  \
static TwStaticObject<Type> ThisSingleTon##Type##FUN;\
static Type* FUN()\
{\
    return TwStaticObject<Type>::singletonInstance(ThisSingleTon##Type##FUN);\
}
```

Than, to register:

```
class Register{
public:
    Register(){
        atom = RegisterClassEx(&tCls); 
    }

    ATOM atom;
};

TwDefine_Static(Register, _register);
```

call _register() when you want.

Answer (score -1):

This is classic double-check locking. The main problem here is following:
Let's say, thread one enters the function for the first time. Checks atom to be 0, locks critical section and starts inialization. It sets the atom to non-0, and this change is reflected in the main memory (because it can!). However, the results of RegisterClass call are **not** reflected in the main memory, and stay inside CPU cache. After that, CPU decides it is overheat and goes to sleep.

At this perfect time, another thread enters the function on a different CPU. It sees ATOM being non-null, and happily returns it - but whoever is going to use the atom is up for a big surprise!

**EDIT**

Just noticed the compiler in question. Since VS2010 does not support thread-safe static variables, there is also another problem here. It is possible that atom will be re-initialized to 0 second time. This can happen in a following scenario:

thread one enters the function, checks hidden 'inited' value associated with atom, finds it to be false, sets the atom to 0, inited to true, enters critical section and registers class - at which point it goes to sleep. Second thread enters, checks the inited value, finds it to be false - because there is no reading fence on it's side, so it can read stale value - and sets atom to 0. Need I continue?

Obvious solution (not the best one, but given the constraints) is to enter critical section before definition of static.

Comment: You should add a solution too. That probably comes down to extending the critical section since VS2010 naturally is not very good with C++11.

Comment: This is wrong. Once `RegisterClassEx` returns, the window class is fully registered, and the `ATOM` is valid. Like all USER functions, it is thread-safe out of the box. And you are missing the real issue: An `ATOM` is not atomic, and changes may not be reflected in other threads.

Comment: @nwp The question is not asking for solution, which is, of course, obvious - use critical section around the atom as well.

Comment: @IInspectable, why? Unless RegisterClass has it's own fences inside it (of which I know nothing about and I somehow doubt specification states so) this is not wrong.

Comment: @IInspectable, I am not missing anything. There are tons of ways to synchronize changes to ATOM from other threads without ATOM being atomic type.

Comment: USER objects (like window classes and windows) are backed by kernel memory. Access to this memory is fully thread-safe. This was introduced when Windows moved from coöperative multitasking to preemptive multi-threading. If this weren't the case, existing code would stop working.

Comment: @IInspectable, being thread safe and having memory fences are two different concepts.

Comment: You can safely assume that memory barriers are in place, when API calls modify kernel memory (as is the case with `RegisterClassEx`).

Comment: @SergeyA You seem to misunderstand what Windows means by `ATOM`. It does not refer to atomicity. [An *atom* in the Windows API is basically an index into a table of strings.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649053%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) [There are several different groups/types of atoms in the Windows API](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150429-00/?p=44984/) and they are used to avoid costly string comparisons for evaluating equality and/or uniqueness. Other toolkits have different names for these; for instance, GLib calls them *quarks*.

Comment: `RegisterClass()`, upon success, returns the atom that Windows assigned to the class name string; you can use these in place of the class name in a call to `CreateWindow()`, for example. No one actually uses class atoms directly anymore; nowadays all that's important is that the atom value is nonzero, which means the class was successfully registered.

Comment: The bug in the code the OP posted is not that there's a chance for a partially registered class to come out; once `RegisterClass()` returns successfully you get the class atom and there's little chance of the variable having some intermediate value. Rather, what *could* happen is that the thread calling `RegisterClass()` is preempted *between* the return from `RegisterClass()` and the assignment, and another thread tries to register the same class. This other thread will get a zero return because the class was already registered, and the program will incorrectly give up!

Comment: (Unfortunately I do not know what race condition IInspectable is thinking of; I do know what I just said likely isn't what they are thinking of...)

Comment: @andlabs, this will not happen, since another thread will have to enter criticla section - which would be locked. After entering critical section, it will check atom again and find it 0. Your scenario is not plausible.

Comment: @andlabs: Memory access is unordered. Both the compiler and the CPU can re-order memory reads and writes. You need to establish memory barriers to ensure that memory access is ordered across threads. `std::atomic` is one solution to this. The code as posted has another issue: `atom` isn't properly cv-qualified, and the compiler can evict the memory access inside the critical section and re-use the value loaded into a register before. Even though threads are serialized, the code can still work off of a stale value.

Comment: @IInspectable, no, you are wrong. Compiler is not allowed to perform such optimizations across opaque function calls, such as EnterCriticalSection which provides necessary barriers.

Comment: A compiler can implement any optimization as long as it respects the *as-if* rule. A compiler that knows that `EnterCriticalSection` will not modify `atom` can implement this optimization. If you believe that this isn't true, please provide a reference to the C++ Standard that explicitly forbids this optimization.

Comment: @IInspectable, this is simply not true. No compiler can know that EnterCriticalSection imposes no memory barrier (if anything, it knows it does) and no optimizations can ignore the fact. No further references are needed, this is exactly what prevents it - as-if rule would be violated. You seem to be really confused.